# How to config Netezza in Datagrip?

Tags: jdbc, netezza, datagrip

Does anyone knows how to configure a Netezza Database Connection in Datagrip?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. First, you should download the JDBC Driver from your Netezza Host machine; it's usually located at /nz/kit/sbin/nzjdbc3.jar
2. Then you create a new Driver on the 'Data Sources and Drivers' dialog. Click on the '+' button on the upper left corner.
   [check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNWrR.png)
3. Now you complete the new drivers options as follows:
   [image: Image of the driver window]

   It's very important to fill the field **Class** with the value **org.netezza.Driver**.

You should add the file that you get on step 1 in the section 'Driver files'. Leave the 'Advanced' tab blank and save.

1. Now you can create a new Data Source based on this new driver. Click on '+' button on the upper left corner of the 'Data Sources and Driver' and choose 'Netezza Driver' or whatever name you enter on step 3.
2. Complete the Data Source options as follows:
   [image: Image of the data source window]

And finally choose which schemas you want to access on the 'Schemas' tab.

That's all. At least in my case, works very well.